# How to create a long click event on a list view which shows options similar to context menu

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I create a context menu after a long click event on a list view in this script?

I need to add an `OnLongClickListener` and show a context type menu as a result of a long click on one of the items in the listView.

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     contactList = new ArrayList<>();

     ListView lv = getListView();

     // Listview on item click listener
     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                 int position, long id) {
             // getting values from selected ListItem
             String nomer = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomer))
                     .getText().toString();

             Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + nomer));
             if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
 Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                 return;
             }
             startActivity(callIntent);
         }
     });
 }

 class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         // Showing progress dialog
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
         pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
         pDialog.setCancelable(false);
         pDialog.show();
     }

     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
         // Creating service handler class instance
         ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

         // Making a request to url and getting response
         String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url.get(), ServiceHandler.GET);

         Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

         if (jsonStr != null) {
             try {
                 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                 // Getting JSON Array node
                 contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                 // looping through All Contacts
                 for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                     JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                     String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                     String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                     String nomer = c.getString(TAG_NOMER);
                     String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                     String url = c.getString(TAG_URL);

                     // tmp hashmap for single contact
                     HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                     // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                     contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                     contact.put(TAG_NOMER, nomer);
                     contact.put(TAG_URL, url);
                     contact.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                     // adding contact to contact list
                     contactList.add(contact);
                 }
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         } else {
             Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
         }

         return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         super.onPostExecute(result);
         // Dismiss the progress dialog
         if (pDialog.isShowing())
             pDialog.dismiss();

         /**
          * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
          * */
         ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                 MainActivity.this, contactList,
                 R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_NAME, TAG_NOMER, TAG_DATE,
                 TAG_URL}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.nomer,
                 R.id.date });

         setListAdapter(adapter);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Register forcontext menu in your ListView:

```
registerForContextMenu(lv);
```

Add the overriding methods:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
      super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
      if (v.getId()==R.id.list_view) {
          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
      }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
      switch(item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.add:
         // add stuff here
            return true;
          case R.id.edit:
            // edit stuff here
                return true;
          case R.id.delete:
        // remove stuff here
                return true;
          default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
      }
}
```

And finally, add the menu file like below(Customize according to your requirement)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <item android:id="@+id/add"
              android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
              android:title="@string/menu_add" />

      <item android:id="@+id/edit"
              android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
              android:title="@string/menu_edit" />

       <item android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/my_icon_delete"
             android:title="@string/menu_delete" />

</menu>
```

in res/menu folder